# Ошибка установки php модуля mongodb. PHP версии 8.2.6, а Laravel версии 9.52.8

Tags: php, mongodb, composer, pecl

я пробовал устанавливать через composer, но установка завершается ошибкой:

```
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Vue.js\vue-laravel-crud-project\server> composer require jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update jenssegers/mongodb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb[dev-change-release-notes, dev-pr_2318, v3.9.0, ..., 3.9.x-dev] require mongodb/mongodb ^1.11 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.11.0, ..., 1.16.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.16.x-dev is an alias of mongodb/mongodb dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[dev-feat-dirty, dev-master] require illuminate/support ^10.0 -> found illuminate/support[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.4.0, ..., v1.4.3, v2.0.0-alpha, ..., 2.0.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev] require illuminate/support 4.2.* -> found illuminate/support[v4.2.0-BETA1, ..., 4.2.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.8] require illuminate/support 4.0.x -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0-BETA2, ..., 4.0.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.1.0, ..., v1.3.2] require illuminate/support 4.1.* -> found illuminate/support[v4.1.0, ..., 4.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.1.0-beta, ..., v2.1.5] require illuminate/support 5.0.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.0.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.1.6, ..., 2.1.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.2.0, ..., 2.3.x-dev, v3.0.0-alpha, ..., v3.2.3] require illuminate/support ^5.1 -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.2.7, ..., 2.2.x-dev] require illuminate/support ~5.1.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., 5.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.3.0-alpha, ..., 3.3.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^5.5 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.0, ..., v3.5.0] require illuminate/support ^5.6 -> found illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.5.1, ..., v3.5.3] require illuminate/support ^5.8 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, ..., 3.6.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^5.8|^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[dev-develop, v3.7.0, ..., 3.7.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha.1] require illuminate/support ^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., 3.8.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - mongodb/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongodb ^1.16.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.11.0, ..., v1.11.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.12.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.12.0, ..., v1.12.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.13.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.13.0-beta1, ..., v1.13.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.14.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.15.0, ..., v1.15.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.15.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb * -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[dev-change-release-notes, dev-feat-dirty, dev-master, dev-develop, dev-pr_2318, v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.3, v2.0.0-alpha, ..., 2.3.x-dev, v3.0.0-alpha, ..., 3.9.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha.1, 4.2.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

А percl почему-то у меня не работает

Comment: `пробовал устанавливать через composer` это вы устанавливаете "расширение" (для конструктора запросов, вроде как..) для работы с mongodb.. Само расширение устанавливать не так. `percl почему-то у меня не работает` что значит  не работает? [Installing the MongoDB PHP Driver on Windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php#mongodb.installation.windows)